# android Core Splashscreen API makes launcher icon black in dark mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-splashscreen

I am implementing new Splashscreen API to my app in android. In light mode everything looks good but in dark mode icon is completely black. Anyone have any idea?[image]

Comment: Same issue, I put forceDarkAllowed=false everywhere and I'm using assets in separate -night folders but no luck... I'm on androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha02

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @Manu no I couldn't solve it

Comment: You can use the answer from here, even though it's a react library it's overriding core android, but you need to create in drawable-v23+(drawable-v24..) folder

https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash/issues/287#issuecomment-1031713661

@Abdullah *

Answer (score 0):

Try using implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0' instead of androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha02.
They have fixed the dark mode issue. But the images and colors still appear a little darker than what we set in themes.